# Find the maximum of $x^2y$ subject to $x^2+2y^2=6$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, lagrange-multiplier

I know I have to use the method of Lagrange multipliers so I want to find $\lambda$ in

$$\langle 2xy,x^2 \rangle=\lambda \langle2x,4y \rangle$$

This gives me $y =\lambda$ but my multivariable calc is very rusty. Do I use $\lambda$ to find $x,y$ to plug into $x^2y$?

Comment: "I know I have to use the method of Lagrange multipliers" -- Unless this is homework and it specifically says to use Lagrange multipliers, you definitely don't need to.  In fact, it's equivalent to find the maximum of $(6-2y^2)y$ subject to $6-2y^2 \geq 0$.

Comment: Note that $2xy=\lambda 2x$ also has the solution $x=0$.

Comment: @BrianMoehring its for the GRE subject examination, the notes in the solution said use LaGrange multipliers.

Comment: @MichaelMorrow ahh so I cannot divide by $x$?

Comment: @HossienSahebjame It's good practice for Lagrange multipliers, but in the exam, you can choose any method you'd like.

Comment: @BrianMoehring how would you do it on the GRE subject exam with only 2.5 minutes per question lol

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I mentioned in the comments, if this isn't a homework problem for which you'd lose points for not using Lagrange multipliers, it would be better just to use substitution to change it to a single-variable calculus problem.

In particular, note $x$ only appears as $x^2$ and we may solve $x^2 + 2y^2=6$ for $x^2 = 6-2y^2$.  We may now maximize $$x^2y = (6-2y^2)y$$ subject to the condition $6-2y^2 = x^2 \geq 0$.  That is, maximize $f(y) = 6y-2y^3$ on the interval $[-\sqrt{3}, \sqrt{3}]$.

Setting the derivative equal to zero to find the critical points gives $$0=f'(y)= 6-6y^2 \implies y=\pm 1$$ and then checking these points gives a maximum of $f(1) = 4$.

Answer (score 1):

Yes express $x,y$ in function of $\lambda$, replace in $x^2+2y^2=6$ to find the value(s) of $\lambda$ then calculate $x^2y$.

Don't forget to check $x=0$ also as pointed out by Michael, and to verify that the obtained value(s) is effectively a maximum (and not a minimum for instance).

For a visualisation make $k$ vary on this drawing:

https://www.desmos.com/calculator/fxuqcug9eq

The maximum is greatest value of $k$ such that the blue curve has intersection points with the ellipse (i.e. when it is tangent, thus the Lagrange multipliers method).